# Why does random.randint(1,2**n - 1) returns the n bit long integer and not simply the integer itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random 
def samplegcd (n, size ): 
""" repeats the following " size " times : Choose two 
random integers , n bits long each ( between 1 to 2**n -1). 
Checks if they are relatively prime . 
Computes the frequency and the derived approximation to pi.""" 
count =0 
  for i in range (0, size ): 
    if gcd ( random.randint(1,2**n - 1) , 
       random.randint(1,2**n - 1)) ==1: 
    count += 1 # the dreaded += 
return count /size , (6* size / count )**0.5
```

Why does `random.randint(1,2**n - 1)` return the n bits long integer and not simply the integer itself?

Comment: "symbolize"? What do you mean by that? And what's "the integer itself"?

Comment: because that's how base 2 number systems work?

Comment: why by `random.randint(1,2**n - 1)` not an integer is chosen but its length in bits?

Comment: an integer is chosen, and it has n bits. If you want an integer between 1 and n, use `randint(1,n)`.

Comment: but why does here `2**n - 1` instead?

Comment: It's the difference between being paid 6 figures, and being paid $6. We want a number up to `n` digits long, not a number up to `n`, so we use `2**n-1`, which is the highest n-bit number.

Comment: why `2**n-1` is the highest n-bit number? why not `2**n`?

Comment: For the same reason `10**6` (1 million) is the first 7 digit decimal number, rather than the last 6 digit decimal number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
random.randint(1,2**n - 1)
```

This returns random integer in a range from 1 to 2^n-1. There is nothing to do with python. It is mathematical question. If we want to generate n-bit integer (integer which has not more than n bits) then we should generate number in a range from 1 to MAX_N_BIT_VALUE. What is the maximum value which can be fit into n bits? It is 2^n-1.

maximum 2-bit value is 11 (binary) = 3 (decimal) = 2^2-1.

maximum 3-bit value is 111 (binary) = 7 (decimal) = 2^3-1.

maximum 4-bit value is 1111 (binary) = 15 (decimal) = 2^4-1.

Comment: may you explain the concept of n-bit integer- in the case of n=2 isn't  the max_n_bit_value is 4: because of 00,10,01,11?

Comment: maximum 2-bit value is 11 (binary) = 3 (decimal) = 2^2-1

Comment: is `2**n - 1` converting to decimal the maximum  n-bit value?

Comment: Yes, it is. Note: I use ^ instead of ** in my examples for "power"